# Finding difference in two dates in same month in sql using month interval

Tags: sql

I am trying to calculate difference in two dates using `datediff` function and month interval. The problem is that my dates are in the same month so when I calculate difference in months, it's 0. But for my problem, as long as I have the presence of the date, I must count it as 1.

For example:

```
datediff(month, '2021-01-01', '2021-01-05')
```

equals 0, but for my case, I need it to be equal to 1.

Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `CASE` statement. For example, the following code works on SQL Server:

```
select CASE
          WHEN datediff(month,'2021-01-01','2021-01-05') = 0 THEN 1
          ELSE datediff(month,'2021-01-01','2021-01-05')
       END
```

Comment: thank you so much for this. this definitely helps!
a follow up to the previous request: I am trying to basically determine how many months in 2021 a member was enrolled with us.  so i have patient id, effective start date, effective end date and its pretty messy.
for ex: i have 2021-01-01 eff start date  to 2021-01-05 as eff end date....then for same patient... 01-06-2021 to 01-13-2021  then 01-14-2021 to 03-01-2021 and then 03-02-2021 to 04-07-2021 all the way until end date sometime in december 2021. .. i get 11 rows for this member after min and max because theres no row for February.

Comment: You might want to ask a different question and then provide some examples of what you are trying to do.